# Community Cloud Link with Sales Cloud?

Tags: community, customer-community, community-cloud

I'm looking at the pricing of Communities (community cloud), I see the below pricing.

My questions:

1. Should a customer community be combined with an enterprise edition of Salesforce to use? (I'm assuming a Yes) i.e., to maintain a community, I need to first have a Salesforce edition?
2. Can a customer community be maintained separately without linking it to any Salesforce edition? (I'm assuming a No)

With the pricing below, so this price is in **additional** to the Salesforce Edition  that I buy, correct?

Can someone confirm my assumptions?  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, answers to your questions.

1. Yes, Customer Community needs to be used with [Enterprise or Performance Edition](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_overview.htm) of Salesforce. It is also available in Developer orgs and the orgs still on the old Unlimited Edition.
2. No, Customer Community is not designed as a standalone product.

Pricing is additional to Salesforce licences.