# Getting Started - Community Cloud

Tags: chatter, community-cloud

I've just been asked to get up to speed on Community Cloud to set it up for a company and this will be my first experience with Salesforce platform.

The organization of the products seems insane and I'm not sure if you need to buy a base "Salesforce" product before buying Community Cloud. ([This post implies you do](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136790/community-cloud-link-with-sales-cloud)). Although I don't see a base Salesforce product on the website, just Sales Cloud.

Can anyone gives tips about the right process for setting this up and the advantages over using this than the Chatter API which seems to be the inner workings of Community Cloud.

Comment: I am sure instead of asking here you should contact your account excutive they will be better person to answer this based on your requirement.

Comment: @TusharSharma I will but is there any blog posts or any resources you found useful?

Comment: Check my answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all as your link already answer you need to purchase Salesforce license and based on that you need to purchase additional license to create and manage community and then community user license that user will access your community.

Now the Sales cloud it's a platform provided from Sales for normally used by user whose main target is Sales and it's most commonly used among other Marketing, Service cloud, Wave cloud.

[Sales Cloud](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfvYCFpM3PAhXIQ48KHTmoBdkQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.salesforce.com%2Fproducts%2Fsales-cloud%2Foverview%2F&usg=AFQjCNFiBh_n0kElII_7HR9JUY2dEvZfGA)

In community your user can access Few standard license and custom Object and its most used where you have large number of external users (Like a shopping cart).

Chatter (Find reference link) has 3 different license and used most of the time for internal user who want to get latest update from your company or need smaller access then full platform license and normally internal users of your company.

In your use case I think you have three options available
 - Chatter Plus 
 - Employee Community
 - force.com license

Differences: - force.com allows to create or edit accounts and contacts, while chatter/community are read only on account/contact - all 3 licenses share a common limit on 10 custom objects - none of the 3 license types grants access to opportunity, pricebook, product, order -> need a full CRM license to work on those objects - employee portals allows users to issue their own cases or review cases

if you are not running your internal ticket management over SF (using case) and don't need to create account/contact go for cheapest license, which is chatter plus - otherwise one of the two others

Here is some links for your reference

- [User Licenses in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm)
- [Chatter User License](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm)
- [Community User License](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US)

For pricing details you should contact your account executive they can provide you details based on number of license you need.

If you need any help related to configuration in community you should check Trailhead.

- [Community Cloud Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/community_cloud_basics)